# Stack in infinite loop while using if in java

Tags: java, while-loop, infinite-loop

I have a program which should read from a imported TXT and convert each line to a variable base on either"Art" or Jewellery

The file import works fine and the list of lines works fine as well.

The problem is when i try to compare the string from list with "ART", it won't match.
But the tricky thing is, I used printout to print the String, it actually give me the string "ART"!!

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(importedFile);
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    stringList.add(sc.nextLine());   
}

// start from the third line of txt
int i = 2;

// stucked in infinity loop!!!!!
while (i < stringList.size()) {
    String type = stringList.get(i);
    System.out.println(type);
    System.out.println(stringList.size());

    if (type == "ART") {
        // add art consignment information
        consignmentName = stringList.get(i + 1);
        System.out.println("art");
        i=i+2;
        type = stringList.get(i + 2);
    } else if (type == "JEWELLERY") {
        //add JEWELLRY consignment
        consignmentName = stringList.get(i + 1);
        System.out.println("Jewellery");
        type = stringList.get(i + 2);
        i=i+2;
    }
}
```

The txt document is:

```
Walt Richman’s Estate Collection    
5    
ART    
Water Lilies    
JEWELLERY   
Diamond Solitaire in White Gold
```

The output of

```
System.out.println(type);
System.out.println(stringList.size());
```

is

```
"ART" and "36"and it is in a infinity loop.
```

I have insert a "System.out.println(art)" in if loop, and it's not printed, which means it never go into it

So I really don't get when

"System.out.println(type)" = ART, then why if(type=="ART") won't work

It's really weird, can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issues have been seen:**

**1**. you did not increment variable i , so while `(i < stringList.size()) {` will never be `flase`.
       Therefor, you need to increment `i` variable

**2**. "The problem is when i try to compare the string from list with "ART", it won't match."
       because you need to use `equals()` to compare two String not `==`

**why**?

> **1**. **equals()** compare againts the content which what you are looking for
>
> **2**. **==** compare the reference if references are looking at the same location

Answer (score 0):

You need to increment your variable i.

Answer (score 0):

you never incrememt i. thus i stays at the original value and your while loop runs forever...